# MDL Textbox - label does not float

Tags: html, css, material-design-lite

Given the following page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Document Properties</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:regular,bold,italic,thin,light,bolditalic,black,medium&amp;lang=en" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.1/material.light_blue-light_green.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />


    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <style type="text/css">
        .page-content {
            padding: 20px;
        }

        .search-result-width {
            max-width: 900px;
        }

        .card-width {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            min-width: 100%;
        }

        #contentGrid
        {
            padding:50px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body style="font-family:Roboto; font-size:16px; background:#fafafa;">
    <div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout">
        <header class="mdl-layout__header mdl-layout--waterfall">
            <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
                <div class="mdl-layout__title">
                    Document Properties
                </div>
                <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
                <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--expandable
                  mdl-textfield--floating-label mdl-textfield--align-right" id="searchBox">
                    <label class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon" for="srchText">
                        <i class="material-icons">search</i>
                    </label>
                    <div class="mdl-textfield__expandable-holder">
                        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" name="sample" id="srchText" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
            </div>
            <div id="progress" class="mdl-progress mdl-js-progress mdl-progress__indeterminate" style="width:100%; opacity:0;"></div>
        </header>
        <main class="mdl-layout__content">
            <div class="mdl-grid" id="contentGrid">
                <form action="">
                    <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
                        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="txtScanDate" />
                        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="txtScanDate">Search again?</label>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </main>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var id = getParameterByName('Id');
            var jqxhr = $.getJSON("GetPatientDocument.ashx?DocumentId=" + id, function () {

            }).done(function (data) {
                var i = 0;
            }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('There has been a problem retrieving document properties - ' + textStatus + ' ' + errorThrown);
            }).always(function () {

            });
        })

        function getParameterByName(name, url) {
            if (!url) url = window.location.href;
            name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
            var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
                results = regex.exec(url);
            if (!results) return null;
            if (!results[2]) return '';
            return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The txtScanDate field in the form - the label should float, when you input - however when embedded in this page it does not float at all. Even if I paste code from pages where the floating page is working it still does not actually float.

I've tried this in both firefox and IE10 so not a browser issue. I have also tried taking it outside the contentGrid, removing the padding on contentGrid but still no floating label - anyone got any ideas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another Homer Simpson moment :(

I am missing the reference to the MDL scripts

```
<script src="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.6/material.min.js"></script>
```

It should be inserted just prior to the scripts at the bottom of the `<body>` tag and before the existing script tag.

Only gave the answer so that others who are scratching their heads remember to check that first.